# The probability of victory in battle

Tags: probability

mikhail lermontov and nikolai martynov met for battle
Everyone shoots in turn,and we know that Martynov fired first
$p_m=${The probability of martynov eliminate lermontov, by a single shot}
$p_l=${The probability of lermontov eliminate martynov, by a single shot}
I need to calculate what the probability of each (in a separate event) is to beat the other.
(with chain rule)
I tried to think in that direction:
$B=${martynov eliminate lermontov}
$p(B)$=$p_m*p({\overline{p_l}}|p_m)$

Comment: Could you edit into your question what you have tried.  Note that if they both miss then they start again in the same position

Comment: Yes I will add it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the probability of Martynov winning overall is $p_B$ then you can say he wins either if he has an immediate win or if they both miss and then start again so

$$p_B=p_m + (1-p_m)(1-p_l)p_B$$

and solving for $p_B$ gives

$$p_B= \frac{p_m}{p_m+p_l-p_mp_l}$$

Comment: You will be able to explain how you got the  $$p_B= \frac{p_m}{p_m+p_l-p_mp_l}$$ i was unable to convey the factors properly

Comment: @complex_stock: $p_B=p_m + (1-p_m)(1-p_l)p_B $ $\implies p_B-(1-p_m)(1-p_l)p_B =p_m  $ $\implies p_B- (1-p_m -p_l+p_mp_l)p_B =p_m   $ $\implies (p_m +p_l-p_mp_l)p_B =p_m $ $\implies p_B =\frac{p_m}{p_m+p_l-p_mp_l}$

Comment: Now it's completely clear, thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2):

The probability is found using sum of infinite geometric series assuming each shoots independently

$$p_{m}+ (1-p_{m})(1-p_{l})p_{m}+((1-p_{m})(1-p_{l}))^{2}p_{m} + ((1-p_{m})(1-p_{l}))^{3}p_{m}+......= \frac{p_{m}}{1-(1-p_{m})(1-p_{l})}$$.

You repeatedly consider the event when both misses and then M succeeds and then add them up using geometric series .

Comment: Now that's clear, thank you very much

Comment: @complex_stock you should also have a look at Henry's argument . There he conditioned on the first event and used symmetry of the situation. Sometimes when things get way to complicated for the geometric series argument it is very very helpful to do what Henry did. Needless to say that both methods will give the same answer.